# Select group of rows with same value

Tags: php, mysql

i am building a game where players can kill players and so on, whenever there is a kill it gets inserted in to a database like,

ID - Killer - Killed -

I want to have a killstreak stats page with the highest kill streaks.

The killstreak will be how many kills in a row a player got but i am unsure how i can select them from the table by "who has the most rows with grouped ID's, 10, 11, 12 etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*kills in a row*"?  Or, more to the point, what would interrupt such a "*killstreak*"?  Presumably the player being herself killed, but would other players' kills also interrupt the streak?

Comment: Yes when either that player dies or somewhere else in the game someone kills someone else that will interrupt the killstreak

Comment: You must therefore have a means of sorting your kills by the order of gameplay.  Does the `ID` column suffice (i.e. is it guaranteed to increase strictly monotonically with gameplay)?

Comment: Do you have a column in a table as to who killed the player?

Comment: @JamesBlack: Wouldn't that be the `Killer` column?

Comment: Its an auto increment, so if player A gets 5 kills in a row her id's might be, 1,2,3,4,5 then someone else kills someone else and gets the id 6, so player A had a 5 killstreak

Comment: @user3128232: Just because the column has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute does not *guarantee* that it will strictly increase with insertions.  One could, for example, explicitly specify some lesser value (e.g. of a previously deleted record).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more difficult because you're looking at contiguous records instead of total records so `GROUP BY` doesn't do it's normally useful thing here. I'm not sure you can do this in your kill records table (at least not easily or scalably).

What I would do if I were you is I would add an index to the players table. If you kill another player, increment the index. If you die, reset the index. It's simple to do, had minimal overhead and would easily allow you to build a leader board if you sort by that `streak` column.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this on a recent game.

Basically, If they win, add one to their killstreak. If they lose or get killed, set their killstreak to 0. I've always had an extra column in the `users` table as `killstreak`.

Then, you can sort this in a "Hall of Fame" of sorts. It's a lot easier than trying to sort through another table.